# Primary Key Type Guid or Int?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wondering what is the recommended type for PK in sql server? I remember reading a long time ago [this article](https://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/) but now I am wondering if it is still a wise decision to use GUID still.

One reason that got me thinking about it is, these days many sites use the id in the url for instance `Course/1` would get the information about that record.

You can't really do that with a guid, which would mean you would need some new column that would be unique and use that, what is more work as you got to make sure each record has a unique number.

Comment: *You can't really do that with a guid*, why not? Not only you can, but it is also much better than using a sequential numeric id.

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer here and this is highly subject to opinion. There really is nothing wrong with a guid being the primary key. But make certain it is NOT the clustered index.

Comment: @RacilHilan better is a matter of opinion and situation. There are plenty of times where a sequential number is preferred. And other times where it might be a better choice because the need for obfuscating the value is not as important. There are many use cases for both guids and sequential numbers.

Comment: @SeanLange Read my comment again carefully. I was specifically referring to using the id in a URL. In that context it is not an opinion. Using a sequential number can have serious implications.

Comment: @RacilHilan on the contrary. There are times when it doesn't matter at all in a url. And other times where it has near criminal level of incompetence. Just because it is the key and in the url does not make it suddenly a bad choice.

Comment: @RacilHilan why? If the resource is sensitive it should only be shown to authenticated users authorised to see it. not rely on security by obscurity. It can leak information about number of entities or order of their creation but often this is not sensitive.

Comment: @SeanLange And how is your comment is *on the contrary*? You said *And other times where it has near criminal level of incompetence* :), so that's not *on the contrary*, that's inline with what I said :). Yes, not always security measures are needed :).

Comment: @RacilHilan here is what you said " I was specifically referring to using the id in a URL. In that context it is not an opinion. Using a sequential number can have serious implications. ". You implied that in a URL it is not an opinion and always a problem. I merely suggested that is not always the case.

Comment: @chobo2 . . . The answer to your question is simple:  There is no recommended type.  As for the balance between GUIDs and auto-incremented columns, the author of the blog does a pretty good job laying out the pros and cons.  Database developers more often arrive at the opposite conclusion, preferring ints to GUIDs.  That does not make one way "right" or "better than" the other in all cases.

Comment: StackOverflow itself does use integer primary keys in URLs liberally despite the article you link being written by Jeff! This Question is Id 50298740

Comment: @SeanLange No, your interpretation is incorrect. Yes, it is not an opinion and always a problem, but how important that problem is to your system depends on the system. Just because it is a problem, doesn't mean it's worth solving it for all systems. Read my answer below. A sequential ID in the URL presents several problems (always), but in some systems those problems are critical, and in other systems those problems are minor and OK.

Comment: @MartinSmith Read my answer for details. It has nothing to do with *security by obscurity*. Yes, I agree that you must do your authorisation carefully, but bugs happen even in the most secure systems. With sequential IDs, a bug in security can be easily exploited, while with random IDs it's nearly impossible. It's an added measure of security that can be useful in some scenarios.

Comment: @SeanLange - what do you mean by "But make certain it is NOT the clustered index"

Comment: You're going to get fragmentation faster if you do. Since they aren't sequential, and successive inserts aren't any more likely to be tagged on to the end of the index versus the middle. And it's larger than an INT, so you're going to get page splits quicker. If your fill factor isn't 100% then this will be even quicker. Just an observation

Comment: If you are reading articles about SQL Server, go to the experts - two (from countless) examples are:   https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5105/sql-server-performance-comparison-int-versus-guid/ and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2010/05/27/guid-vs-int-debate/. I never use guids in any of my databases. Codd fanatics will say a surrogate key is no key at all so that's not even a question, and others will say guid is the best option. The truth is that as everything else, **it depends on many factors.** One thing is sure, though: **never use guids for you clustered index.**

Comment: Here is a great article on the topic of guids as the clustered index. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/

Comment: @RacilHilan while I would not use an identity value in a url can you explain why in your opinion that is a problem? Say for a site that is just displaying public information how would using an identity in the url be an issue?

Comment: @SeanLange Like I said, the same problem can be critical for some systems and minor for others. Just because a system displays public info, doesn't mean it is OK to use numeric IDs. Similarly, just because a system is only for authorised users, doesn't mean it's a critical problem to use numeric IDs. There are other considerations, so read my answer for more details. The issue is not always a strict security access issue. Even guessing the order and the number of records can be a big issue to some systems without any access breach.

Comment: @SeanLange Here is hypothetical example. See the edit in my answer. IMDB likes to come across as the movies database :) and most of their data is *"public information"*, but they use sequential IDs in their URLs. Now, let's say that someone wants to verify their claim. He can simply search for one of the movies of the year, check the ID, and subtract the ID of one of the first movies in the database. By comparing the result to the known number of movies until now, he gets a good idea about how many movies are possibly missing. That can be detrimental to some businesses.

Comment: @SeanLange To summarize, any unintentional leak of information is considered a security issue. For some businesses that issue can be ok, but for others it can be detrimental. And just for the sake of accuracy, I assume that your comment *using an identity in the url* is just a misuse of words, because we're not talking about exposing any identity here, we're talking about exposing sequential IDs. Exposing non-sequential IDs like GUID is a partially different story and may or may not be an issue depending on the scenario for other considerations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is never a "one solution fits all". You have to carefully design your architecture and select the best options for your scenario. Both `INT` and `GUID` types are valid options like they've always been.

You can absolutely use `GUID` in a URL. In fact, in most scenarios, it is better to use a `GUID` (or another random ID) in the URL than a sequential numeric ID for security reason. If you use sequential ID, your site visitors will be able to easily guess other users' IDs and potentially access their contents. For example, if my profile URL is /Profiles/111, I can try Profile/112 and see if I can access it. If my reservation URL is Reservation/444, I can try Reservation/441 and see what happens. I can easily guess other IDs in the system. Of course, you must have strong permissions, so I should not be able to see those other pages that don't belong to my account, but if there is any issues or holes in your permissions and security, a breach can happen. While with `GUID` and other random IDs, there is no way to guess other IDs in the system, so such a breach is much more difficult.

Another issue with sequential IDs is that your users can guess how many accounts or records you have and their order in your database. If my ID is 50269, I know that you must have almost this number of records. If my Id is 4, then I know that you had a very few accounts when I registered. For that reason, many developers start the first ID at some random high number like 1529 instead of 1. It doesn't solve the issue entirely, but it avoid the issues with small IDs. How important all that guessing is depends on the system, so you have to evaluate your scenario carefully.

That's on the top of the benefits mentioned in the article that you mentioned in your question. But still, an integer is better in some areas, so choose the best option for your scenario.

**EDIT** To answer the point that you raised in your comment about user-friendly URLs. In those scenarios, sequential numbers is the wrong answer. A better solution is a unique string in the URL which is linked to your numeric ID. For example, the Cars movie has this URL on IMDB:

```
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0317219/
```

Now, compare that to the URL of the same movie on Wikipedia, Rotten Tomatoes, Plugged In, or Facebook:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cars_(film)
https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/cars/
https://www.pluggedin.ca/movie-reviews/cars/
https://www.facebook.com/PixarCars
```

We must agree that those URLs are much friendlier than the one from IMDB.

Comment: Well I mean is that with a GUID in your url, I don't really consider it that friendly if your user has to for some reason type out the url manually(might be rare) but it could happen.

Comment: Yes, and that exactly the problem that I pointed out in my answer. Being *friendly* here is often a problem, not a feature. In the very rare scenarios where you really want your users to type the URL, you can use numbers, but that means you only have a limited number of records, because typing 50298740 (the IF of this question) is not much easier than typing a GUID. :)

Comment: See the edit in my updated answer regarding your point about user-friendly URLs.

Comment: Yea that is better, I guess one other thing that I thought of that might be a bit of a problem is right now the site I am recreating has ids, an internally they use those ids to find the user. So they will type in 4041 to pull up a user. If you have GUID it's not as easy to do this same sort of search. I know I could just have email search or something else, but say I have to support that, then I guess much like the url I would have to have another unquie id?

Comment: Numeric ID and GUID are both not good options for search done by users unless it is a physical ID like the one on your student card or library card. It is still not the best option for that, but it is acceptable. Notice though that those IDs are usually very big numbers. Searching by email or similar methods is much nicer in most cases. We all remember our emails, but do we remember our library numbers? For that reason, banks often allow you to create a username and link it to your bank card number, so you don't have to type it except for the first time.

Comment: Yea, I agree that an ID of 4041 is not the best, I rather search by email, company name and etc, but I am not sure yet I may have to keep it a INT but I still may still do better url names.

Comment: Nobody can give you that answer without more detail about your requirements. Like I said, there is no one solution that fits all. INT is good in many scenarios, and GUID is good in some. That's why I only focused on the ID in the URLs, and with that out of the way, you can use the article that you linked to in your question as a good base of comparison to choose between INT and GUID for your system. Do you need those benefits of GUID? If yes, then go ahead with it. Otherwise, stick to the best performer, INT.

Answer (score 1):

My experience has been that the only time a GUID is needed is if your data is on the move or merged with other databases.  For example, say you have three sites running the same application and you merge those three systems for reporting purposes.

If your data is stationary or running a single instance, int should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on small, medium, and large scale implementations(100k+ users) with SQL and Oracle. The major of the time PK type of INT is used when needed. The GUID was more popular 10-15 years ago, but even at its height was not as populate as the INT. Unless you see a need for it I would recommend INT.

Answer (score -2):

According to the article you mention:

> GUIDs are unique across every table, every database, every server

Well... this is a great promise, but fails to deliver. GUID are supposed to be unique **snowflakes**. However, reality is much more complicated than that, and there are numerous reasons why they end up not being unique.

One of the main reasons is not related to the UUID/GUID specification, but by poor implementations of it. For example some Javascript implementations rank as the worst ones, using pseudo random numbers that are quite predictable. Other implementations are much more decent.

So, bottom line, study the specific implementation of UUID/GUID you are and will be using. Don't just read and trust the specification. Otherwise you may be up for a surprise, when you get called at 3 am on a Saturday night by angry customers.

Comment: Have you ever actually seen a duplicate guid that was generated? The odds are absurdly small of that happening.

Comment: Yep, I agree. They really small.

Comment: So small that it is hardly worth mentioning. I calculated once that you could give every person on the planet 100,000 guids and at that number created there is a possibility of a single duplicate. Insignificant enough probability as to say it is going to happen.

Comment: I agree with Sean that the odds are so small that this answer is almost pointless. However, it's worth mentioning that the first version of GUIDs used the MAC address of network cards for part of the GUID, so on systems with no network cards (they used to be more common at that time than now), the generated GUIDs can have much more duplicates. I don't think there are systems that are still using version 1, but it's good to know.

Comment: Nope, not really small of a chance, depending on the engine you are using to generate UUIDs.